# Consider a branching process $\{X_n , n \geq 0 \}$ in which the offspring distribution is binomial $(k,p)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, binomial-coefficients, markov-chains, markov-process

Consider a branching process $\{ X_n , n \geq  0  \}$ in which the offspring distribution is  binomial $(k,p)$. Find probability of ultimate extinction when $k = 3$.

So I've tried this:

$P_k = P(\lambda = t) = {3 \choose t} p^t (1-p)^{3-t} $

$ \phi(s) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty p_k s^k = p_0 s^0 + p_1s^1 +p_2s^2 + p_3s^3  $ (as  $k =3$)

$ \phi(s) = (1-p)^3 + 3p(1-p)^2 s + 3p^2(1-p)s^2 + p^3s^3$

I've gotten till here but I'm unsure if I'm on the right track and if right, how do I proceed?

Thanks!

Comment: The extinction probability is the smallest fixed point of $\phi$ in $[0,1]$, i.e. the smallest $s \in [0,1]$ such that $\phi(s) = s$. See e.g. Theorem 1.7 [here](https://www.uni-muenster.de/Stochastik/lehre/WS1011/SpezielleStochastischeProzesse/Ch_1.pdf).

Comment: Also, you can eliminate some trivial cases: if $\mathbb{E}[X_1] = pk \leq 1$, then the process is (sub-)critical and the extinction probability is $1$.

Comment: @Michh, So are you saying that since $(1-p)^3$ is ≤ 1, then the extinction probability is 1, so $(1-p)^3$ would just = 1?

Comment: @codelearner I don't believe I am saying that.

Comment: @Michh, so then are you saying that since $(1-p)^3$ is ≤ 1, then extinction is inevitable, so you don't need that term?

Comment: No, he is saying that if $pk\leqslant 1$ (the mean of the offspring distribution) is at most $1$, then extinction occurs with probability $1$. Nothing to do with the expression $(1-p)^3$.

Comment: Your approach is correct, but it requires one to solve a cubic equation, which can result in very ugly expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\mu=3p$ be the mean of the offspring distribution. If $\mu\leqslant 1$, then the probability $\pi$ of extinction is one. If $\mu>1$, then $\pi$ is the unique solution to the equation $\varphi(s)=s$ on the interval $(0,1)$. Solving
$$
(1-p)^3 + 3p(1-p)^2 s + 3p^2(1-p)s^2 + p^3s^3 = s
$$
yields the solutions
\begin{align}
s &= 1\tag1\\
s &= \frac{2 p^3-3 p^2-\sqrt{4 p^3-3 p^4}}{2 p^3}\tag2\\
s &= \frac{2 p^3-3 p^2+\sqrt{4 p^3-3 p^4}}{2 p^3}.\tag3
\end{align}
By inspection, $(3)$ is the correct solution (since it yields numbers between zero and one when $\frac13<p<1$).